# Check for user in iSeries rmtcmd

Tags: vbscript, ibm-midrange

My new user creation website is almost done, I have all the vbscript I need to create the users on both the iSeries and AD, I have a check to make sure the user doesn't exist in AD and notify the creator if it does. All I have left is to find a way to check for an iSeries user before the process begins and notify if it already exists.

Does any one know of a rmtcmd I can use to perform this check? I've looked everywhere I can without calling IBM, which will be my next step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User profiles are object type ***USRPRF** in library **QSYS**.  You can use the [**CHKOBJ**](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/cl/chkobj.htm) command to check if it exists.  There is more information in the documentation about [Checking for the existence of an object](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rbam6/check.htm).

```
CHKOBJ OBJ(profile) OBJTYPE(*USRPRF) AUT(*OBJEXIST)
```